# WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 Proxy Service managemen UI doesn't work when clustering is enabled

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm tested clean installation of WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 with clustering enabled and remote registry mount as described [here](http://ajithvblogs.blogspot.com/2012/09/create-jdbc-mount-to-wso2-governance.html):

axis2.xml:

```
<clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="true">
```

Tried to list existing services and create new proxy services but neither list funcnction nor any of proxy services types wizards didn't work giving lot of [exceptions](http://pastebin.com/KraHaYqW)

Then I disabled clustering:

```
<clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="false">
```

The mount still existed and mounted w/o errors but obviously clustering didn't work being disabled.

Is that a bug or clustering requires some additional configuration to avoid such errors? And do I really need to enable clustering in case of remote registry mount?

Thanks,
Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there was a configuration errors in registry mounting configs in that blog. So it's updated now and please do the mounting configurations again by referring that blog.

Comment: Blog entry still states that the clustering should be enabled. Please see Configure Governance Registry-> 5) and Configure ESB -> 5) however the code snippet shows that clustering is disabled on both ESB and GREG:  <clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="false">